# QProcess working example - C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, qprocess

I am trying to start external programs and to communicate with them.

I want to run this application in background using QProcess. And also pass commands as well from this code to this process.

Can someone throw light on this and direct me accordingly to execute commands as well when code is running.

Something like this in python but for c++ using QProcess

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['mpg321', '-R', 'anyword'], stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write('LOAD test.mp3\n')
```

Comment: The `popen()` function takes two arguments: the command string and either `"r"` or `"w"` depending on whether you want to write to the standard input or read from the standard output of the command that's run.  The partial error message you show is giving you that information — command and mode.  If you want to relay your program's standard input to the command you run, you'll need to loop, reading data from standard input and writing to the successfully opened `f` file stream.  And you should consider using `<cstdio>` in place of `<stdio.h>`; your existing code is C code (as well as C++).

Comment: I have something similar, in my case I use shared memory. In the shared memory I have a command buffer that one of the process writes in and the other read from.

Comment: popen( "mpg321 -R ewqe", "w" )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QProcess subprocess;
subprocess.start("mpg321", QStringList()  << "-R" << "anyword");
if (!subprocess.waitForStarted())
    return false;

subprocess.write("LOAD test.mp3\n");
```

Comment: Is it in c++? 
because I am aiming for c++ code.
When I tried to run it.. i.e. #include <QProcess>
It is showing : fatal error: QProcess: No such file or directory
Can you help me with this

Comment: I am trying using sudo apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev
But still its showing same error.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to install QT in my linux (raspberry)

Comment: QProcess is part of the Qt Framework.
You will need to install the Qt headers.
Maybe something like this: apt-get install qt-dev-tools

Comment: Sure.. I il try and let you know

Comment: apt-get install qt-dev-tools  and sudo apt-get install qtcreator
Still not working..same error

Comment: Your project is in CMake? Use find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS QTCORE) in you CMakeLists

Comment: No..i am just creating a small code. 
and compiling using g++ test.cpp -o test  
 Stil not working.

Comment: It's a lot of work manually build. See: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/com_cpp/Cpp/programming/qt/makeqt.htm Recommend you use QMake or CMake to it.